# Table or view not found-convert hive table to spark dataframe

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, sbt, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to do the following operation:

```
import hiveContext.implicits._

val productDF=hivecontext.sql("select * from productstorehtable2")
println(productDF.show())
```

The error I am getting is

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found:
>   productstorehtable2; line 1 pos 14

I am not sure why that is occurring.

I have used this in spark configuration

set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse")

and the location when I do describe formatted productstorehtable2

> hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/productstorehtable2

I have used this code for creating the table

```
create external table if not exists productstorehtable2
(
device  string,
date  string,
word  string,
count  int
)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
location 'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/hadoop/hive/warehouse/VerizonProduct2';
```

I use sbt (with spark dependencies) to run application. My OS is CentOS and I have spark 2.0

Could someone help me out in spotting where I am going wrong?

---

edit:

when I perform println(hivecontext.sql("show tables")) it just outputs a blank line

Thanks

Comment: Are you querying select in same database where you cretaed table.

Comment: @mrsrinivas, I added as default.productstorehtable2 and i get the error  Table or view not found: `default`.`productstorehtable2`; line 1 pos 14;